# ¿Obtener una respuesta de dos modelos relacionados en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy tratando de obtener una respuesta en mi controlador, parecida a la siguiente:

```
{
  "Córdoba": [
    "Ayapel",
    "Buenavista",
    "Canalete",
    "Cerete"
  ],
  "San Andrés y Providencia": [
    "Providencia",
    "San Andrés y Providencia"
  ],
}
```

Tengo dos tablas una llamada **departments** y otra **cities**:

```
departments: id, name
cities: id, name, department_id
```

Ya tengo relacionado los dos modelos:

**Modelo Department:**

```
class Department extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');
    }
}
```

**Modelos City:**

```
class City extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function department(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Department');
    }
}
```

El método que implemente en el controlador es el siguiente:

```
  public function getDepartmentCities(){

        $departments = DB::table('departments')
                     ->select('departments.name')
                     ->get();

        $array = array();

        foreach($departments as $d){
            $array[] = $d->name;
        }

        return response()->json([
            'code' => 200,
            'data' => $array,
            'message' => 'Datos recuperados correctamente'
        ]);
    }
```

Pero solo me trae los departamentos:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "data": [
        "ANTIOQUIA",
        "ATLÁNTICO",
        "BOGOTÁ, D.C.",
        "BOLÍVAR",
        "BOYACÁ"
    ]
}
```

Como puedo anexarle las ciudades a cada departamento?

Cualquier aporte se agradece,

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, haciendo uso de las `colecciones`:

```
$results = Department::
   select('name as department', 'cities.name as city')
   ->join('cities', 'cities.department_id', 'department.id')
   ->get();
```

Posteriormente, haces la agrupación, usando [`collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby):

```
$collection = collect($results);
$grouped = $collection->groupBy('department');
```

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya pude resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Ventaja :

Tienes los modelos declarados y sus respectivas relaciones

Desventaja:

- Aunque tienes esa parte cubierta no la implementas entonces queda desaprovechado.

Problema:

No haces el join respectivo incluso Con el query builder y en concecuencia no obtienes el resultado esperado.

Solución

Construye así tú query:

```
Department::with('cities')->get();
```

Para depurar un poco los datos y **acercanos** a la estructura de salida que esperas podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
$data = Deparment::select(['id', 'nombreDeparment'])
                 ->with(['cities' => fn($query) 
                                => $query->select(['nombreCiudad', 'department_id']) 
                        ])->get();
```

Donde de cada entidad obtenemos las propiedades deseadas, que en este caso sería de `Department` el nombre del mismo y de la relación `cities` el nombre de cada ciudad.

Comment: Es correcto, ya implemente el query y me consulta los datos, pero me los trae todos, como puedo estructurar la consulta para que me los traiga en el formato deseado.

Comment: Todos los datos departamentos con sus ciudades, como en este formato  "San Andrés y Providencia": ["Providencia",   "San Andrés y Providencia"],